# SQL select compare columns vs compare column to value

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a table with fields:

```
long id;
String field1;
String field2;
String status1;
String status2;
Boolean compareResult;
```

`status1` and `status2` have some specific values (enum). `compareStatus` is `true` if `status1`==`status2`, otherwise `false`. All 3 above fields are indexed. Say my table has around 1M records, is field `compareResult` helpful for business that needs to find all records that have different status ? I mean between `select * where status1=status2` and `select * where compareResult=true` which is better ?

Comment: 1M isn't that much (for Oracle, at least). Run them both (several times) and compare the result. Then you tell us. Also, check explain plan for both statements.

Comment: Oracle does support boolean data types in tables, so your question is not relevant.

Comment: ```boolean``` is just for representation, I will use spring jpa to query of course

Comment: My first thought is, without testing, that `select * where status1=status2` won't use an index but `select * where compareResult='TRUE'`will. But the best is to do some test as @Littlefoot suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The index on `status1` or `status2` is not used for `select * where status1=status2`. So a full scan is performed.

But the index an `compareResult` is used for `select * where compareResult='TRUE'`. So it's likely faster using the second query.

BUT, depending on your actual machine (IO and CPU speed, amount of RAM etc.) and wether the number of rows is going to increase over time, ymmv.
I suggest doing some quick tests with more or less real data and see how the server performs.

Hint:
Since `compareResult` will only contain two distinct values (`'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` or `0` and `1` or whatever you use to represent the boolean value) you may use the `COMPRESS` clause when creating the index.